# String split method is returning empty string array

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I want to know why the string split method is returning an array of two empty strings when I use this method with a forwarding slash.

```
"/".split("/") // => ["", ""]
```

Comment: [Specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.split). Also relevant: Wikipedia entries for [Substring](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) and [Empty string](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string split function considers empty strings as acceptable outputs for splitting. So:

```
"a".split("a") == ["",""]; // is true, since
"a" == "" + "a" + ""; // is true; and more importantly,
["",""].join("a") == "a"; // is true
```

In short, the string split function has to give empty strings so that the `.join()` operator is the inverse of split.

Otherwise, if `"/".split("/")` gave `[]`, then `"/".split("/").join("/")` would be `""`, which violates this inverseness.

If you want to actually get an empty array, you could do `"/".split("/").filter(i=>i!="")`, or just `"/".split("/").filter(i=>i)`. Or some other variant.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), it will divide the string into ordered sub strings.
It will consider space as well.